# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 413

Tags: android, android-volley

Trying to upload an image as **Base64** to server and receiving the response:

> BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: r request= [lifetime=6927], [size=497],
>   [RC=413], [retryCount=0] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected
>   response code 413 for **SERVER-URL**

Answer (score 1):

> **HTTP Response Code : 413 Payload Too Large**
>
> Request entity is larger than limits defined by server; the server might close the
> connection or return a Retry-After header field.

So the solution to this problem is to compress the image first to a reliable size, let's suppose it can be 1 MB, and then upload to server.

Here is the method which I created to fetch a compressed version of image as a`File` object:-

```
private File getCompressedFile(Context activity, String filePath) {
    final long FILE_MAX_SIZE = 1024L * 1024L;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.isFile() && file.length() < FILE_MAX_SIZE) 
    
        return file;
    
    else {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, false);
        File output = new File(activity.getCacheDir(), "tempUploadFile.jpg");

        try {
            if (!output.isFile())
                //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                output.createNewFile();

            OutputStream fOutput = new FileOutputStream(output);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOutput);
            fOutput.flush();
            fOutput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return output.length() < FILE_MAX_SIZE ? output : getCompressedFile(output.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, you need to know how I upload it as a Multipart Object to server?

Comment: No, i want to upload image in base 64 format . I mean total code of your suggested above one.

Comment: Instead of 'File' as return type for the method, just convert above object 'bitmap' to Base64 (as you may have done in your code already) to use in the required form and return that.